# how to apply a signal after a period of time in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, timedelay

I simulated a system with Simulink.  Now , I want to apply controller signal to system
after a time, for example after 20 seconds.  It means that the sys. works 20s without
controller and after it the controller is applied.

Which block can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the controller inside a [Triggered Subsystem](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/triggeredsubsystem.html) and set the trigger signal to go high after 20s, for example using a [Clock](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/clock.html) block and a [Compare to Constant](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/comparetoconstant.html) block, set to `>=20`.

Comment: Next time, please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem, so that other users with similar issue can find answers easily.